# XCode debugger breaks in pthread

Tags: c++, macos, debugging, pthreads, xcode8

I'm using XCode to debug a program written in C++ / Obj-C / C. The program integrates Civetweb in order to be able to accept HTTP requests. 95% of the times, when I start the program in debug mode, at the first HTTP request I perform the XCode debugger stops and shows the following 'code snippet':

```
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_cvwait:
0xa1668304 <+0>:  movl   $0x131, %eax              ; imm = 0x131 
0xa1668309 <+5>:  calll  0xa166a408                ; _sysenter_trap
->  0xa166830e <+10>: jae    0xa166831e                ; <+26>
0xa1668310 <+12>: calll  0xa1668315                ; <+17>
0xa1668315 <+17>: popl   %edx
0xa1668316 <+18>: movl   0x58d5d0f(%edx), %edx
0xa166831c <+24>: jmpl   *%edx
0xa166831e <+26>: retl   
0xa166831f <+27>: nop
```

With debugger cursor pointing at +10 address (pointed by the arrow).
If I try to let it continue, I can see the snippet is within `_pthread_cond_wait`:

```
->  0x23ed080 <+647>: addl   $0x30, %esp
```

... and if I let go the program I see in the logs that the last meaningful event is a thrown exception in our TCP connection acceptor class:

```
Can't Accept Software caused connection abort
```

This happens very frequently, but not always: 1 time out of 15 I'm able to successfully start the program. I can't say what is happening here: the same code on Windows runs without problems. Do you have any idea what may be causing this?

Comment: I'd go with the cause being related to the code that you didn't post ;)  But using the tried and tested crystal ball technique, are you sure your mutex is still in scope?

Comment: The code I didn't post is quite complex and convoluted, I wouldn't know which part to post :(

I wouldn't know if it is still in scope, but since the remaining 5% of the times it goes smoothly I would exclude bugs caused by "static" environment like (C++) scopes. But, I'm not a multithreading expert so... maybe I'm missing something your crystal ball sees :) How could I check if the mutex is in scope? Thank you anyway!

Comment: well, using a debugger would be the obvious way ... let the application crash in your debugger and then you can see exactly what it's doing.  I'd suggest trying to remove the threads completely and having it single threaded as this may highlight issues without the thread complexity.